# Using Jest and Enzyme to call a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test a React component.  I am trying to test my form validation rules when submitting a form.  The tests need to cover all possible cases of this function

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { createPassword, confirmPassword } = event.target.elements;
    if (createPassword.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      setPassValidationError("*Passwords must match!");
    } else if (createPassword.value.length < 8) {
      setPassValidationError("*Passwords must be at least 8 characters long!");
    } else if (createPassword.value.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
      setPassValidationError(
        "*Passwords must contain at least one uppercase letter!"
      );
    } else if (createPassword.value.search(/[!@#$%^&*]/) < 0) {
      setPassValidationError(
        "*Passwords must contain at least one special character!"
      );
    } else {
      props.updatePassword({
        uid: props.uid,
        token: props.token,
        new_password: createPassword.value
      });
      event.target.reset();
    }
  };
```

This function is pretty straight forward `createPassword` and `confirmPassword` are the values for 2 different input fields.  When the form is submitted and this function gets called I am testing the password on different criteria.  If the password is not strong enough, the `setPassValidationError` hook is called and updates a state variable.

I am currently trying to test the function with a password shorter than 8 characters.

```
it("passwords must be 8 char long", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<NoAuthPasswordChange />);
  const passInput = wrapper.find("#create-password");
  const confirmPass = wrapper.find("#confirm-password");
  passInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: "QQQQQQ" } });
  confirmPass.simulate("change", { target: { value: "QQQQQQ" } });
  const submitButton = wrapper.find("#submit-button");
  submitButton.simulate("click");
  expect(wrapper.find("#password-validation-error").text()).toContain(
    "*Passwords must be at least 8 characters long!"
  );
});
```

Jest is telling me that `#password-validation-error` cannot be found (expected 1 node found 0).  Now this particular part of the code is only rendered if `passValidationError` has data.

```
{passValidationError ? (
   <h2
     className={styles.passwordError}
     id="password-validation-error"
    >
    {passValidationError}
    </h2>
  ) : null}
```

I'm not sure if I just have a simple bug in my test or if something more advanced needs to be done in order to use Jest and have a function call a hook update.

Edit: I am beginning to wonder if the `event` parameter required by the `handleSubmit` function is problematic due to the function being called by Jest.

Answer (score 0):

This can be cause by not updating the component itself. Have you tried to force your wrapper to be re-rendered:
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html

Comment: This was a good idea.  Unfortunately it didn't solve my issue.  I am wondering if the issue could be that the function requires an event as a property, but an event is not happening when it gets called via Jest.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue.  The test needs to call the form submission on the form element itself and not via a button click.  So instead of `submitButton.simulate("click")` I need to simulate a submit on my form element.  I am unsure why this solution works and the posted code does not.